# Convert String to Date Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a string row like this: `20190116`.

> How I can convert it to Date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date) function in standard SQL. For your example, you can do this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d','20190116')
```

Comment: It works :) thanks

Comment: Any idea why this would produce: "Failed to parse input string "12102021""? My date is a string just like OP and looking for a way to return a formatted date in my query.

Comment: should work if you indicates the right format `PARSE_DATE('%d%m%Y','12102021')`